# Geopandas PostGIS connection

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas

I recently started using Geopandas in python for some of my spatial work and am very pleased with it - I'm currently trying to read in PostGIS features and don't quite understand how to parameterize the database connection, and it didn't seem clear in the documentation:

```
GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom', crs=None, index_col=None, 
    coerce_float=True, params=None)
```

This is likely a very simple question, all I wanted to know is what needs to go in 'con' - I assume a string with database connection information? But in what format? Setting 'sql' seems straightforward.  Any help greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You can look in the pandas `read_sql` docs, which is used by geopandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Example:

```
import geopandas as gpd

import psycopg2  # (if it is postgres/postgis)

con = psycopg2.connect(database="your database", user="user", password="password",
    host="your host")

sql = "select geom, x,y,z from your_table"

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom' )
```

Comment: `psycopg2` is specific to postgres, `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` is generic and can handle connections to most DBMS

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the example above doesn't work any more because GeoPandas doesn't accept `con = psycopg2.connect(...)`, and instead returns the following error:

```
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  df = pd.read_sql(
```

It seems like `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` is the only way now.