# SQLAlchemy pass parameters with GeoPandas.from_postgis

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, postgis, geopandas

I want to pass in parameters to a sql query when using GeoPandas [from_postgis](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#GeoDataFrame.from_postgis) functionality with SQLAlchemy.

> classmethod GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom', crs=None, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None)

I have looked at a previous similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732075/geopandas-postgis-connection) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314342/python-sqlalchemy-pass-parameters-in-connection-execute) which suggests to use SQLAlchemy's [textual SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) option. However, this requires access to con.execute which isn't included in the GeoDataFrame from_postgis option.

Could you suggest the best way to pass the parameters to SQL? If not directly in from_postgis, then how best to construct the full SQL string separately and passing it in as the first sql argument to from_postgis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For textual SQL, you can add parameters by using [`.bindparams`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.bindparams):

```
query = text("select * from foo where bar = :a").bindparams(a=1)
```

For queries you construct in SQLAlchemy, bind parameters are automatically included:

```
foo = Table(...)  # you need to define foo
query = select(["*"]).select_from(foo).where(foo.c.bar == 1)
```

You can also directly pass parameters via the `params` parameter of `from_postgis`, if that's more natural:

```
df.from_postgis(text("select * from foo where bar = :a"), params={"a": 1})
```

**Do not use `str.format` as the other answer suggests because it's vulnerable to SQL injection.**

Comment: I found that geopandas / psychopg did not like the **:param_name** naming style in the sql text, but it did work with **%(param_name)s** style.

Comment: @Nij Note that in this case the colon style is handled directly by SQLAlchemy, regardless of database backend. If you're using psycopg2 directly then yes, you need to use the `pyformat` style.